# express.js роутинг и обработка ошибок

Tags: node.js, express

Доброго времени суток,

Только недавно начал изучать node.js с javascript и застрял на правильной обработке ошибок.

Вот код роутера(router.js):

```js
router.get('/person/:idperson', function(req, res, next) {
  pool.query('SELECT nickname, regdate, place, birthdate, sex, aboutme FROM person WHERE idperson = ?', req.params.idperson, function(err, rows, fields, next) {
    if (err) return next(err);  //выбрасывает ошибку mysql-запроса в app.js
------- Как обработать ошибку возникшую в этой части - непонятно        
if (!rows[0]) res.render('patrials/error', { pageTitle: 'Персона не найдена', errormesage: 'Такого человека нет'})
    else res.render('person', { pageTitle: rows[0].nickname+' | Профиль', sqlperson : rows[0]});
-------
  });
---- При этом ошибки возникающие тут(если написать), отлично выбрасываются в app.js
});
```

Вот обработчик ошибок(app.js):

```js
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('patrials/error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
});
```

P.S. Вообще, по идее, res.render не должен быть во вложенной функции Mysql-запроса, но я пока не разобрался, как заставить рендер ждать ответа функции, запрашивающей информацию в бд, и правильно передать результат в другую область видимости.

Comment: По поводу вашего PS - посмотрите тут: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0). Ну и для обработки ошибок тот ответ также может пригодиться, хоть и не напрямую.